# Ensure that Aurora is started before EC2 instance init

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Part of my EC2 instance init is seeding an Aurora instance, so I need to be sure that my EC2 init is run only after Aurora is fully setup, instead of, say, parallel to its initialization. I don't know currently how Stack Creation behaves, whether it creates instances in the order they are specified in the template, whether it creates them in parallel, or something else.

What do I need to ensure the ordering, so that Aurora is set up first, and the EC2 only afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "DependsOn" : "myDB" tag to the resources block that defines the AWS::EC2::Instance

See this documentation

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html